# Kubernetes' High Availability Leader Lease

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, etcd

I have a question regarding Kubernetes' leader/follower lease management for the kube-controller-manager and the kube-scheduler: As far as I understand Kubernetes tracks the current leader as Endpoints in the `kube-system` namespace.

You can get the leader via

```
$ kubectl get endpoints -n kube-system

NAME                      ENDPOINTS                   AGE
kube-controller-manager   <none>                      20m
kube-scheduler            <none>                      20m
```

then e.g.

```
$ kubectl describe endpoints kube-scheduler -n kube-system

Name:         kube-scheduler
Namespace:    kube-system
Annotations:  control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader={"holderIdentity":"controller-0", ...}
```

The current leader is the `holderIdentity` of the `control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader` annotation.

My question:

Lease management like acquiring leases, renewing leases, time to live, etc. is implemented in [leaderelection.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/leaderelection/leaderelection.go) on top of Kubernetes Endpoints. Is there a specific reason lease management is not implemented directly on Etcd with "out-of-the-box" Etcd primitives like Etcd's compare and swap operation and time to live on objects?

**Edit(s)**

- add Etcd compare and swap
- add Etcd time to live

Comment: What out of the box etcd primitives are you talking about?

Comment: I would probably turn to Etcd's compare-and-swap operation and Etcd's time to live on objects.

Answer (score 0):

A few reasons:

1. Etcd might be running externally to Kubernetes' network, which means network latency
2. Etcd could be busy/loaded and therefore slow
3. The etcd cluster is very likely to have fewer nodes than the Kubernetes master, making it less reliable

Comment: AFAIK Endpoints are Kubernetes Objects, too, and are therefore stored in Etcd as well. So issues 1.-3. would equally apply to Endpoints.

Comment: @dtornow stored on etcd *after* the election process, therefore, not suffering from issues 1-3. Storing an object vs. the whole leader-election dance... ;-)

Comment: I'm not positive that's the case: AFAIU the [Leaderelector](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/leaderelection/leaderelection.go#L239)'s  `tryAcquireOrRenew` will delegate the request to the [Resourcelock](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/leaderelection/resourcelock/endpointslock.go#L39)'s `Get`/`Create`/`Update` which in turn talk to Etcd on each request.

Comment: @dtornow updating a record in etcd != using etcd for leader election, you won't find any functions defined in etcd's [leader election mechanism](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/clientv3/concurrency/election.go) in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, only the API server should have access to etcd.  Keep in mind that if etcd was used for leader leases by convention, custom controllers and operators using leader election would also need access to etcd which would be inadvisable given how critical the data stored in etcd is.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#securing-etcd-clusters